# opencv framework with opengles trows error?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opencv, opengl-es

I tried running a basic opengl program from [this link](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/HelloOpenGL2.zip). I can run it successfully. Now I need some functionalities of opencv to be added in this. 
So I added opencv framework from [this link](https://github.com/aptogo/FaceTracker).

After adding the framework I changed the files to .mm and its compiling good. The problem comes when I add "cv::Mat Variable". I get the below error. What would be the reason for this?

The below is the error I get When I add "cv::Mat Variable".

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_gzclose", referenced from:
      _cvReleaseFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)
      _cvOpenFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)
  "_gzeof", referenced from:
      icvEof(CvFileStorage*)      in OpenCV(persistence.o)
  "_gzgets", referenced from:
      icvGets(CvFileStorage*, char*, int)in OpenCV(persistence.o)
  "_gzopen", referenced from:
      _cvOpenFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)
  "_gzputs", referenced from:
      icvPuts(CvFileStorage*, char const*)in OpenCV(persistence.o)
  "_gzrewind", referenced from:
      _cvOpenFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I have done work on openCV with iPhone SDK, will be help if you share your source code.

Comment: The code I have already shared the link.. My first link is the code.

Comment: openGL code is running fine, I want the source code after you have merge the both.

Comment: @Will Thanks for your reply.I added "cv:: Mat name" in "OpenGLView.mm" my code in  thats it..

Comment: ok, you problem is you haven't added the openCV framework correctly, you have to put correct header paths and necessary stuff correctly.

Comment: yeah I have Done. or Can you guide me through?

Comment: @Will yeah I have Done by adding the opencv.h file in pch file. or Can you guide me through?

Comment: @Will Can you lemme me know what I have made wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Solves my problem. To add add opencv library file

AVFoundation.framework
ImageIO.framework
libz.dylib

should be added. And this link explains clearly about this. http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/